# How can I scan GTIN/GS1-IR barcode with zxing js in angular?

Tags: angular, barcode, barcode-scanner, zxing-js

I'm using livestreaming barcode scanner in my project but I have problem with scanning **GTIN/GS1** barcodes. like barcode below

[image]

I have tried all options bellow

```
formatsEnabled: BarcodeFormat[] = [
    BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,
    BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX,
    BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
    BarcodeFormat.EAN_8,
    BarcodeFormat.EAN_13,
    BarcodeFormat.UPC_EAN_EXTENSION,
  ];
```

How can I fix it? is there any alternative solutions?

Comment: When I read the presented barcode with a hardware barcode scanner, the scanner notified me with a 12-digit UPC-A barcode `012345678905`. This should be GTIN if you add a two digit 0 to the beginning to make it `00012345678905`. Isn't there a specification/setting/function for such conversion in ZXing? On the application side, [UPC_A](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/99e9b34f5afc21fdaeead283d5ed0bc1314cbec1/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat.java) should be read and specified, and the notified barcode should be converted to GTIN by the application itself.

Comment: For example, these articles will be helpful. [Ultimate guide to GTINs, EANs and UPCs for Amazon, eBay, Google and Online Selling](https://www.gs1uk.org/our-industries/retail/selling-on-marketplaces/ultimate-guide-to-gtins-eans-and-upcs-for-amazon-ebay-google), [Barcodes: GTIN, UPC, EAN and JAN](https://readme.priceapi.com/docs/barcodes-gtin-upc-ean-and-jan), [How can GS1 codes be converted to UPC/EAN format](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-can-GS1-codes-be-converted-to-UPCEAN-format)